# How to combine table rate shipping and fixed shipping cost per product?

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

I'm using the table rates (price) to calculate the shipping costs. There are some products that have fixed shipping costs. I need the shipping rate with the combination of table rate shipping and the fixed shipping cost of a product.

**For example**: I've a total of 7 products in my cart. 5 of these products are covered by the table rate shipping rates. These 5 products have a total price of $200. The shipping cost of $200 is $20.

The other 2 products have a fixed shipping costs of $10 a piece. The price of these 2 products must not be include into the table rates.

So the total costs of shipping should be:

$20 for the first 5 products + 2 times $10 for the last 2 products.

So the total shipping cost should be $40.

How can I achieve this programmatically or Is there any extension to achieve this concept?

Answer (score 1):

WebShopApps have an extension ProductMatrix which does this. You can do yourself, you just need to write a custom carrier here and then extend tablerates to add in what you need.